# laravel-webpage not available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 4. I have a table which displays data from "cars" table. I want to click at one of car's name and display all information about this vehicle in a new page. I have done this:

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($cars as $car)
 <tr>                                   
   <td> 
   {{ HTML::link('/desc', $car->Description, array('id' => 'linkid'), true) }}</td>  
   {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@showDesc', $car->id)) }}
   {{ Form::hidden('id', $car->id) }}
   {{ Form::close() }}
   <td>
   {{ $car->License }}</td>     
   <td>{{ $car->Make }}</td>     
   <td>{{ $car->status }}</td>                                    
   </tr>                                                            
@endforeach
```

**CarController.php**

```
public function index() {
        $cars = Car::all();
        return View::make('pages.index', compact('cars'));
    }

    public function showDesc() {
      $description = //here want to get name, year, color from "cars" where id = POST['id']
      return View::make('pages.description', compact('description'));
    }
```

//pages description is the new page which will display all information about that specific vehicle                ,

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
Route::post('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@showDesc'));
```

The problem is that browser shows: This webpage not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');` and this will create restful routes to access your controller and in the car controller you should have functions like index(), show($id), destroy($id).
To see what are the valid routes, run `php artisan routes` in your project directory.
if you want to follow the restful pattern which is what you want to do I think by using a resource route. be sure you have the function `show($id)` in your CarController. the route to that function is `cars/{$id}` so in your view make a link to this route:

```
{{link_to_action('CarsController@show',  $car->Description, $car->id)}}
```

I hope this will fix the problem

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: I edited the answer, if it still not working, put default string instead of $car->description.

Comment: It still shows the same error array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array. Even when put a string insted of $car->id

Comment: but path is http://localhost/national/public/cars/62. This means that it gets the id, but why this error?

Comment: controller:   public function show($id) {
        $id = DB::table('cars')->where('id', $id);
        return View::make('pages.desc', $id);
    }

Comment: check first if the function is being called, replace the show($id) function by show($id) { return 'show'.$id;}

Comment: Thank you it displayed the id. But I dont get sth. Why it doesnt pass data from controller to desc view?

Comment: I'm glad that it works now. for passing data to the view use View::make('pages.desc')->with('data', $data); and in your view you will have access to the $data variable

Comment: Thank you :D it's perfect now :D

Comment: I'm glad for you :) you can upvote my comments if they were useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

in your view you have a link to "/description" and in the routes.php file you don't have a route to that link

Comment: I changed it to /desc and still shows the same thing

Comment: edited my question, please take a look. Is there anything to do with the fact that I am using 2 routes for the same controller??

Comment: there is no problem with using 2 routes to the same controller, I'm trying to figure out what is the problem